# Grep by text color

Tags: colors, grep, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have to filter a very verbose log output that the only pattern between messages for warning or errors is the output text color

Is there a way to filter by the output color when using grep?

When I try to use the [color code](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) I have an error due to the `[`

```
$ echo -e "Default \e[94mLight blue"  | grep \e[94m
grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced
```

I managed to be able to filter it by using just `<number color>m`

```
echo -e "Default \e[94mLight blue"  | grep 94m
Default 94mLight blue
```

But it removes all color formatting, changes the output and also has the potential to match a lot of other text that is not just color formatting.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
echo -e "Default \e[94mLight blue"  | sed -n '/\[94m/p'
```

This printed colors for me in zsh. I couldn't manage to include the '\e'

Answer (score 2):

There are several places where this goes wrong:

- The character `[` has a special meaning for `grep`, unless you use the `--fixed-strings` (`-F` in short) option. So it needs to be quoted:

  ```
  grep '\[94m'
  ```
- There is also (seems to be?) no way to specify the *Escape character* (`\e`) directly for grep with `\e`, `\033` or something similar. But you can use *zsh's* `$'…'` quoting to let *zsh* create the *Escape character*:

  ```
  grep $'\e\\[94m'
  ```

  Strings inside `$'…'` will be process like arguments to the `print` builtin. So `\e` will be replaced by the actual *Escape character* and `\` needs to be doubled in order to get a single, quoted backslash.
- Be sure to use `grep` without any options that change formatting, for example `--color=auto`. By default *Oh-My-Zsh* creates an alias named `grep` that includes this option, if it is available.

  You can force *zsh* to use the command instead of an alias by prepending the `command` *precommand modifier*:

  ```
  command grep
  ```

All in all the following command should do the trick:

```
echo -e "Default \e[94mLight blue" | command grep $'\e\\[94m'
```

**Note 1**: This requires *zsh* due to `$'…'`. A more portable version would be

```
echo -e "Default \e[94mLight blue" | command grep $(printf '\033\\[94m')
```

**Note 2**: Unless the log output sets color codes (also) at the beginning of each line or resets them at the end of the line, the coloration of the output may still be broken. In that case you may have to use `awk` in order to get a better result:

```
echo "Default \e[94mLight blue\nDefault \e[94mLight blue" | 
  awk '/\033\[94m/ {printf "%s\033[0m\n", $0}'
```

This appends the reset coder `\e[0m` to the end of each matching line when printing it. Note that awk (at least the GNU version) does not use `\e` to signifiy the *Escape character*, you have to use `033` instead.

---

You can check, whether `grep` is an alias with this command:

```
whence -v grep
```

It is also possible that the environment variable `GREP_OPTIONS` is set to include such options. To check this, you can run this command:

```
echo "${(t)GREP_OPTIONS}: $GREP_OPTIONS}"
```

This shows the type of `GREP_OPTIONS` followed by its value (`type: value`). If the type does not contain `export` or the value is empty there should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to use it in a regex? I want to look for several colors. For now I used multiple `-e` flags, like here: `terraform plan | grep -e $'\e\\[31m' -e $'\e\[B\[32m' -e $'\e\\[33m'`.